# Assign variables to a list pagination

Tags: jquery, list, variables

I am using a plugin, which creates a navigation to a lists of sections in my html document.

I want to insert a custom name for every navigation-point, while its currently "Navigation 1", "Navigation 2", "Navigation 3". At the end it should be something like "Dogs", "Cats", "Squirrels".

The current code is:

```
if(settings.pagination == true) {
    paginationList += "<li><a data-index='"+(i+1)+"' href='#" + (i+1) + "'><span class='icon'><img src='img/icons/icon"+(i+1)+".png' width='20' height='20' alt='icon"+(i+1)+"'></span><span class='link'>Navigation "+(i+1)+"</span></a></li>"
  }
```

I thought about a workaround, because the menu already has the "+(i+1)+" tag to use. So I thought about creating a list of variables

```
var navi1 = dogs
var navi2 = cats
var navi3 = squirrels
```

And use these variables (as they are already numbered starting by 1 say something like

```
take variable "navi(i+1)"
```

How can I do this, as I am not a too skilled jquery developer yet?

Best regards,
Marian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variables are defined in global scope, you can access them via `window` or `this` 
too, like this:

`window.nav1` or `this.nav1`.

This will allow you to use the bracket notation to access these properties, like this:

`window['nav1']` or `this['nav1']`

... and so you can use this notation to apply dynamic names for property names:

`window['nav' + i]` or `this['nav' + i]`.

**UPDATE**

You can use a navigation `array`, then iterate over its items and create the list items. Here is the example:

```
var nav = [ 'dogs', 'cats', 'squirrels' ],
    paginationList = '';

for (var i = 0, i < nav.length; i < l; i++) {
    paginationList += '<li>';
    paginationList += '<a data-index="' + (i+1) + '" href="#' + (i+1) + '">';
    paginationList += '<span class="icon">';
    paginationList += '<img src="img/icons/icon' + (i+1) + '.png" width="20" height="20" alt="icon' + (i+1) + '">';
    paginationList += '</span>';
    paginationList += '<span class="link">' + nav[i] + '</span>';
    paginationList += '</a>';
    paginationList += '</li>';
}
```

In this snippet I created a `nav` array and used the `for` loop to iterate over its items. Inside of loop variable `i` changes its value for each iteration. So in the first iteration `i` is equal to `0`, in the next one `1` and so on, until this condition become false `i < nav.length`, where `nav.length` is the count of items inside of `nav` array.

You can fetch the value of array item using indices, like this: `nav[1]`, which is the second element of the array, because indexing starts at `0`. So inside of loop you access items using `i` as an index, like this: `nav[i]`.

Also I have broken down your *one-line* code to make it more readable.

If anything is not clear, please ask me.

Comment: I suppose it's worth to mention that instead of all these `'nav' + i` variables simple array can be used.

Comment: @Regent The last example is intended to run inside of loop.

Comment: @Regent thanks for your answer! I have read the jQuery documentation about arrays. So your idea is to create one like `var naviarray = [ "Unternehmensprofil", "Technische Kompetenz" ];` and take this array to display the different names as they are sorted in the array?

@KarlenKishmiryan does your comment intend to say, that it could be a problem to use an array?

Comment: @MarianRick If you want to use a programming language, try to learn about the basics first.

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan I am very sorry, maybe because its early in the morning I have missed your answer. Thanks a lot for this suggestion!

I have tried to use this and defined my `var nav = ["cats","dogs","squirrels"]` in global scope and inserted the suggestion `<span class='link'>"+window['nav' + i]+"</span>` which results in a list with the text "undefined". I although tried to make single variables instead of an array `var nav1 = "cats";` with no result.

Is this a careless mistake or is there something crucial wrong?

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan thanks a lot for your very detailed answer. Your explanation gave me a good deeper understanding for using arrays!

Thanks a lot for your time again and keep up your good work! :)